# is there anyway to add a song to a specific playlist that I have previously created manually in iTunesa from ipod

Tags: ipod, playlists

If I am listening to all my music and I hear a song and I think it would be great to add to a certain playlist, is there anyway to do this from the iPod itself, instead of having to remember this from iTunes.

Comment: Won't it remember the amount of times you played it and you can have iTunes set up to play those songs more?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a song to the on-the-go playlist as it is played. This requires an (at least 4th generation) iPod with a screen, shuffles are not supported.

To add a song to the on-the-go playlist simply press the center button for some time until the blue bar flashes. Of course, the on-the-go playlist is visible in iTunes.

More information can be found [here](http://ipod.about.com/od/introductiontotheipod/ht/otg_playlist_ip.htm).

Comment: I always wondered what "On-the-go" did. Thanks!

Comment: @Uwe Honekamp - i wanted to add it to a specific playlist that i created from itunes

Comment: @ooo maybe you should add this constraint to your question, it just says "certain playlist" instead of "specific playlist that I have previously created manually in iTunes.

Comment: @Uwe Honekamp - done